# Numeric output formats

Tags: graphics, output-formatting

I want to print the expression $A[x] = 8020.6596 \times 1.055^x$ as is on a 2D graphic. I included the line

```
Graphics[Text[HoldForm[A[x] = 8020.6596 \[Times] 1.055^x],{2,0}]]
```

in the graphics call, but the first constant insists on printing as $8020.66$. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using `NumberForm`:

```
Graphics[{Inset[A[x] = NumberForm[8020.6596, 10]*1.055^x, {0, 0}]}]
```

Comment: This works, but you can't really use it along with, say, `HoldForm`. So if for example I wanted to output $x^{1/3} + 8020.6596\times 1.055^x$, I can't enclose the whole thing inside a HoldForm and still put the number inside a NumberForm. Why does this have to be so difficult, he whined?

Answer (score 1):

You can use strings for such things.  You can use fractional spaces to adjust spacing, style text using the Format menu, etc.  This does't copy here very well but it is simple in a Notebook:

[image]

[image]